# Target Dependency between two projects in the same workspace

Tags: xcode, macos, build, linker

I'm using Xcode 4.3 to create a framework for OS X. I created a workspace and a project (with a framework target) to go in this workspace.

Now, I want to include & link with a third-party framework which I've also added to the **same workspace** (but not within my project). I clicked the <kbd>+</kbd> button in the "**Link Binary With Libraries**" build phase, and the third-party framework simply appeared in the list of available libraries.

The linked framework shows up red in the Project navigator, as the third-party library has not been built yet (confusingly, though, my project successfully builds — although I'm not yet trying to *use* the third-party framework):

[image]

I was going to solve this by adding it as a Target Dependency, but when I click <kbd>+</kbd> on the "Target Dependencies" build phase, the third-party target doesn't show up in the list.

**How should I properly configure/resolve this dependency?** Also, do I need to create a Copy Files build phase to ensure the framework is copied into my target's Frameworks directory? How would I set that up properly?

Comment: I think Xcode will automatically build it as a dependency since you are linking to it. It might not show up because of this. The framework is probably red because it will only detect the file for the release configuration.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Yes, I think I read that it can automatically detect & build dependencies within the workspace. But why do you say it will only detect the file in the Release configuration? (I just tried Product > Build For > Archive, and it's still red.) And do you think I need to explicitly set up a Copy Files phase?

Comment: Last time I looked, the output references used the path of the release build. Also if you added a previous project to a new workspace, the reference could be referencing a different build location, so that wouldn't work either. If you want to package the framework inside your application, you need to set up a copy files phase.

Comment: Good luck. I found this to be very buggy :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into something similar but with static libs.

- Do what you did to build the framework, build your app (even if it fails, the framework should build)
- Remove the reference to the framework in your app target's link build phase
- Locate the built framework in the Finder (the one built by your app workspace).
- drag/drop it into the app project that uses it. Notice that this time it appears with black color (not red)
- click it, and make sure the Xcode inspector shows "relative to built products" (you may need to change it reference type), and that the path is just the myframework.framework.
- check that it has been added to the app link phase (it should)
- that's the one you can use in the copy/build phase.

Comment: For future readers: this solution came from [this developer forums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/148935) where you can find further discussion.

Comment: Adding `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)` to Framework/Library Search Paths might be helpful.